# Как добавить больше одного файла

Tags: c#, email

Как добавить больше одного файла? есть еще 2 файла с именем rconpro_2.pha,rconpro_3.pha

```
string file = ("rconpro_1.pha");
            Attachment attach = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);

            ContentDisposition disposition = attach.ContentDisposition;
            disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(file);
            disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
            disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(file);

            Message.Attachments.Add(attach);

            Smtp.Send(Message);
            Close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавляй таким же образом все остальные файлы в Message.Attachments:

```
var files = new[]{ "myfile_1.ext", "myfile_2.ext", "myfile_3.ext" };

foreach (var file in files)
{
    var attachment  = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
    var disposition = attachment.ContentDisposition;
    disposition.CreationDate     = File.GetCreationTime(file);
    disposition.ModificationDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
    disposition.ReadDate         = File.GetLastAccessTime(file);
    message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
}
client.Send(message);
```

Comment: Пробовал,не получилось психанул удалил проект если можно код напишите пожалуйста.

Comment: Хз, что тут может быть непонятно. Ответ обновил.

Comment: Спасибо я бы не додумался...